# make scrollbars look the same in every OS?

Tags: jquery, css

Scrollbars get quite a bit of use in the site i'm working on and how they look on some OS's really doesn't fit with the design - especially if someone's running xp!

looking for a lightweight css / jquery method of custom styling my scrollbars?

Comment: Only scrollbars inside the page, yes?

Comment: Man alive, just a passing comment, but if your design isn't working across all platforms your design doesn't work at all! Don't confuse your user, this will ultimately alienate them and you'll lose them forever.

Comment: Please don't: http://lists.evolt.org/archive/Week-of-Mon-20030324/026229.html

Comment: @David: so what's the problem if you can emulate a large amount of that?  IE's `doScroll` method allows you to almost 100% emulate the behaviour of the scrollbars and webkit's scrollbar styling (http://webkit.org/blog/363/styling-scrollbars/) makes it all that much easier (no JS involved).  On certain site designs UI scrollbars can look very much out of place.  If you can get the behaviour of the scrollbar just right, is there any problem with it?

Comment: @ILMV
We're talking about 'fitting with the design' here, i'm not going to employ something that doesnt work!

Comment: @Andy E — getting the behavior "just right" is exceptionally difficult.

Comment: @David - don't exagerate - if users can find a custom scrollbar in computer games they will find it on site too. It's not that designers or users are retarded.

Comment: @easwee That's depends, are all of your audience computer gamers?

Comment: If users have to 'find' scrollbars, then they aren't as effective as the ones they are used to. A user might, for instance, tend to use the spacebar to scroll pages at a time (standard behaviour in a browser, but not in the first example of jScrollPane). If it doesn't work then sure, they can still use the tool, but it will have given them a negative for the UX.

Comment: If the scrollbar is logicaly designed and looks like a scrollbar and is positioned where a scrollbar should be, and has all the functionality it has by default, I see no problem in why not styling it. I saw way to many sites ruined by default scrollbars. Oh and I hope we are talking about scrollbars on page not the browser one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[jScrollPane](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html) will do this for you.

Having said that, you might want to reconsider actually doing this at all - changing a core part of the UI away from something the user is used to could be a usability issue. There's a very real possibility that some users browsing your site may not recognise your custom scrollbars and will wrongly guess that a page can't be scrolled, causing them to miss out on seeing the whole page.

Comment: thanks tobias, this is the kind of answer I'm after!

Ideally i'd like to replicate the windows7 ui, i totally see your point about making sure it's seen as a scrollbar to the user, without them having to think about it